# Getting "captured value declared here" when using local lazy var in Playground

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground

I try to study the effect of local `lazy var`

I have no issue execute the following code in Xcode

### Execute in Xcode

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        run()
    }

    func compute() -> Int {
        print(">>>> compute")
        return 123
    }

    func run() {
        lazy var x = compute()
        
        print(">>>> bye")
        
        if false {
            print(">>>> \(x)")
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I try to following the equivalent code in Playground

### Execute in Playground

```
import UIKit

func compute() -> Int {
    print(">>>> compute")
    return 123
}

func run() {
    lazy var x = compute()
    
    print(">>>> bye")
    
    if false {
        print(">>>> \(x)")
    }
}

run()
```

I am getting error

```
MyPlayground.playground:9:14: note: captured value declared here
    lazy var x = compute()
             ^
```

May I know why is it so?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems to be a bug, reported but still open https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/57632

Comment: From my understanding lazy are met to only be used for property not inside function or method. May be it can compile but I am not sure it is meant to be so.